# How to render components on the same page in react

Tags: forms, reactjs, push

In my design on the top of the page, you can see pictures as links.
When you click on different pictures, the different component is called. 
For example, onClick method show component which is set to true:

```
    state = {
        showPage1: true,
        showPage2: false,
        showPage3: false,
        showPage4: false
      };
      onClick1 = e =>
      this.setState({ showPage1 : true, showPage2: false, showPage3: false, showPage4: false
      });
      //continue with another onClick methods
```

And in the final render method is:

```
render (){
    const src = '/images/image.jpg'
    return(
      <div>
      <Image.Group size='tiny'>
      <Image src={src} onClick={this.onClick1}/>
      </Image.Group>
      { this.renderPage() }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And based on that, the different components are shown on the same page.

```
 renderPage() {
    const showPage1 = this.state.showPage1;
    if (showPage1) {
      return (
          <Page1 submit={this.submit}/>
      );}
```

Now, each component is a form for me, where a user submits details.
When details are submitted, I do not know how to redirect to another component.
For example, if it was `Page1`, then I want automatically redirect to `Page2` and so on.
This is what I have now, but this, of course, does not work.
I am not sure how to call one component after another component if this component does not have link, because it is displayed on the same page.

```
submit = data =>
     this.props.saveComponent(data).then(() => this.props.history.push('/text'));
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that routing is a more sustainable solution for this problem, without installing React Router it seems to me you just need to update your state, don't you? You could include a `currentPage` and `nextPage` property in `data` to indicate which page to transition to. For example:

```
submit = data =>
  this.props.saveComponent(data).then(
    () => this.setState({
      [data.currentPage]: false,
      [data.nextPage]: true
    })
```

This is the kind of task routers are pretty good for though, so rather than doing conditional renders I'd definitely suggest learning more about routes.